# Simple way to loop through numbers in a range with conditional increment or decrement

Tags: c, loops

I'm looking for an elegant solution to evaluate a range of numbers in a single loop from a starting value to an ending value. The thing that is making it difficult is that the starting value can be greater than the ending value so the loop would need to decrement if that is the case, or increment if the starting value is less than the ending value. My code for this implementation works but feels cheap especially with an increment/decrement before the loop starts.

```
 54     number = starting;
 55     if (starting < ending)
 56     {
 57         number--;
 58         step = 1;
 59     }
 60     else
 61     {
 62         number++;
 63         step = -1;
 64     }
 65     do
 66     {
 67         number += step;
 68         fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", number);
 69     } while (number != ending);
```

I'll be adding more to this loop but for now I just want to print the values to see if it prints all the values in the range.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Please don't include line numbers in code snippets. They make it hard to extract the code for testing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is there an easy way to copy code from VIM without the line numbers?

Comment: `:set nonu`, copy, `:set nu` 